# Elm img attribute too many arguments

Tags: elm

I am extremely new to Elm, and I am encountering a problem which frustrates me to no end.
Here is my code:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    img [src "Img1.png", width 300, height 300] []
    div []
        [ input [ onInput ChangeUserInput ] []
        , button [ onClick SaveText ] [ text "Save" ]
        , button [ onClick Clear ] [ text "Clear" ]
        , h1 [] [text model.userInput]
        ]
```

And the error I receive is that

```
The `img` function expects 2 arguments, but it got 5 instead
```

I think its parsing the div tag arguments as img arguments, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Have you imported it? You're not listing your imports.

Comment: Ah yes, it was an import, but now complains about the img tag expecting two arguments and receiving five. Somehow it is parsing the div arguments as img arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view function needs to return a single HTML element.  At the moment it seems you are trying to return two elements: an `img` and a `div`.  The `div` and its two arguments are being picked up as arguments to the `img` because there is nothing in your code that Elm can use to identify the end of the list of arguments to pass to the `img` function.

You will need to wrap them both in an element that contains them, for example, another `div`:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ img [ src "Img1.png", width 300, height 300 ] []
        , div []
            [ input [ onInput ChangeUserInput ] []
            , button [ onClick SaveText ] [ text "Save" ]
            , button [ onClick Clear ] [ text "Clear" ]
            , h1 [] [ text model.userInput ]
            ]
        ]
```